# Jquery Function show hide not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the show query, but the problem is when i have multiple rows, basically i can do multiple show hides which renders its functionality wrong.

What i doing is: clicking on it will show the value and change the text label, but if i do for anotehr another row, it also changes its text and now i end up with two rows having hide label even the show is display the value from the second click.

how can i fix it

```js
$(document).on('click', '.showDiv', function() {
  $("#divData").css('display', 'block');
  $("#divDataData").load('audioDailyCounts.cfm?audioID=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '&_new=' + Math.random());
  $(this).text('Hide Daily +/-');
  $(this).addClass('removeDiv');
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeDiv', function() {
  $("#divData").hide();
  $(this).text('Show Daily +/-');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" class="showDiv" data-id="#audioID#">Show Daily +/-</a>
<div class="row" id="divData" style="display:none;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card-box">
      <div id="divDataData"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68613935/edit) to include the relevant HTML.

Comment: Could there be any problem with having multiple elements with the same ID `divData` ?

Comment: i added the html

Comment: so, you are adding `removeDiv` class to your link, so when removing it will run BOTH the `showDiv` and `removeDiv` event handlers, probably in reverse order they were added

Comment: Like Nico says, you're not supposed to have more than one element with the same `id`. Where's the <a> in relation to the row?

Comment: i am not having that element with same ID, i am just overwriting that div contents with new one

Comment: Create full [mre], I see only one row

Comment: there are some rows with same class but different data-id